# Xtext: Customizing Error msg by unordered groups

Tags: error-handling, message, xtext, unordered

I've defined an unordered group and it works like I expected. The only thing I would like to change is the error msg, which appears when an element of an unordered group isn't modelled yet. Is there an easy way to solve this? I tried already custom checks, but there I got an unexpected behaviour.

Following my rule for the unordered group and the error msg:

```
Element:
    (name=ConfigurationName) &
    (description=Description)? &
    (tool=Tool) &
    (model=Model) &
    (interfaces=Interfaces)? &
    (paramaters=Parameters)? &
    (paramfile=ParamFile)?
;

rule ruleElement failed predicate: {getUnorderedGroupHelper().canLeave(grammarAccess.getElementAccess().getUnorderedGroup())}?
```

I want to change this error msg to something like: "The following elements are required in the configuration:...."

Answer (score 2):

Xtext has a service called SyntaxErrorMessageProvider that is used to reword parser error messages. You have to define your messages on the parser level (so there will be no EMF model to use), but it is possible to get the original error message and the context, traverse it and provide your own error message.

To register this, open the `«YourLanguage»RuntimeModule` class, and add the following method:

```
public Class<? extends ISyntaxErrorMessageProvider> bindISyntaxErrorMessageProvider() {
    return «YourLanguage»SyntaxErrorMessageProvider.class;
}
```

where `«YourLanguage«SyntaxErrorMessageProvider` is a class introduced by you, extending the class `SyntaxErrorMessageProvider`, where you can implement your custom function.

Comment: Thx so far, but I have no clue how to hand over a new error message :/
There is no really documentation how to acces this parser messages..

Maybe it's easier to change my grammar..

Comment: There is indeed no doc available. However, look for elements of your grammar. An example I created before (if helpful): http://git.eclipse.org/c/incquery/org.eclipse.incquery.git/tree/plugins/org.eclipse.incquery.patternlanguage.emf/src/org/eclipse/incquery/patternlanguage/emf/validation/EMFPatternLanguageSyntaxErrorMessageProvider.java

Comment: Ok thank you very much. Why do you use MismatchedTokenException for example? Is here an overview about the different exceptions? For my case it wouldn't work, I reckon?

I'm not really sure what you are doing in your example. Have I to use the IParserErrorContext, to modify the error message?

Comment: The MismatchedTokenException represented a case, when an incorrect token was found in the parse stream. The exception contains the expected and the found token. In our case, sometimes a constant literal was used instead of an identifier, which was rewarded by some low-level, undecipherable error message. I simply identified the simple case we want to override the message and returned it. However, as there is no overview documentation available, you need to infer from the code what kind of exception type represents your issue (e.g. by the debugger in a small example).

Answer (score 0):

I works Automatic Validation customize,I create 
public class MyDslLanguageSyntaxErrorMessageProvider extends SyntaxErrorMessageProvider {
}

And I Register it in the MyDslRuntimeModule: 
public Class bindISyntaxErrorMessageProvider() {
        return MyDslLanguageSyntaxErrorMessageProvider.class;}

But my problem is which package is used for this customization.I used org.xtext.example.mydsl.validation package for create java class .Also I do this customization  with xtend class.I do not find enough source in the internet :(

Answer (score 0):

You can  use Java to write this Custom SyntaxErrorMessageProvider class, but to bind this you can bind in Runtime Module class. Also u can use any package to declare this class but declaring this class in same package where u have Runtime class makes sense